# Long-term visits to other Schengen countries for US residents

Tags: germany, us-citizens, schengen, employment, finland

I'm an American working in Finland.  This Fall, I'll be in Germany from Sept.–Jan. for work.  Since it's longer than 3 months, I know that I need to register my local address. Do I also need to do anything at the Ausländeramt, or is my Finnish residence permit sufficient?  (I only get a local honorarium, and am still paid my usual salary and health/pension/etc from Finland.)

Comment: What type of residence permit do you hold?

Comment: "Type A" which means "continuous".

Comment: Does this web page apply: http://www.nrwinvest.com/Business_Guide_englisch/Coming_to_NRW/Visa_for_Employees1/index.php

Answer (score 4):

Answering my own question to say what happened.

Since I was only planning to stay in Germany for marginally more than 90 days, the *Ausländeramt* just gave me a *Grenzübertrittbescheinigung* that lets me stay until the end of the term at the institute I'm visiting.  (This is less paperwork hassle and certainly cheaper than getting either a work permit or a long-term visa.)

Answer (score 3):

You do need a German residence permit (or a long-stay visa and/or authorization to work, as appropriate). As a U.S. citizen, you can apply for it from within the country but you are not allowed to work without it.

In general, a Finnish residence permit does not make any difference in this scenario. In particular, it does not grant you any right you don't already have as a U.S. citizen (it would exempt you from short-stay visa requirements but U.S. citizens don't need one in the first place).

Comment: I won't be officially working for the place I'm visiting. Can you be more specific?

Comment: @Louis What do you mean by "officially" be working? Either you will or you won't but being paid in Finland and employed by a Finnish company is not necessarily the most important factor. Beyond that, I can't tell you if you need a work authorization or not, but as I said the Finnish residence permit is generally not relevant and the usual rules for US citizens apply so you need some sort of German visa or permit to stay longer than three months in any case, even without working.

Comment: @Louis I assume your Finnish employer wishes to send you to work for a client in Germany for six months.  In this case, it seems, your employer should find out what authorizations will be necessary for this, and help you obtain them.